# Edit a row of a grid control

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a context in a grid control, in which when I only click on the menu, buttons are displayed, when I click on an element, the grid should be enabled for me to edit only the row that I am selecting. I have the grid disabled.
I use devxpress.

Comment: Hi Ronald, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. You should perhaps edit your question, and add some reproducible code you've tried. See: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will increase the chance of it getting answered, and decrease the chance of it getting closed.

Comment: What DevExpress product suite are you using? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET/MVC? HTML5/JS? Xamarin? There's not enough information here to suggest a solution.